# Can't run one python module from another (when run from Eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, fedora

I'm using Fedora 15 64bit and python 2.7

When I run `python test.py` from command line it works well 
but when I run `subprocess.call(["python","test.py"])` from another python module I get

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 557, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 539, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 268, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 233, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 535, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 434, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 287, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix it?

UPDATE: This stack trace I get when run script from Eclipse.

- when I run test.py from CL - it works
- when I run script containing
  `subprocess.call(["python","test.py"])` from CL - it also works
- when I run script containing `subprocess.call(["python","test.py"])`
  from    Eclipse - it fails

Comment: Is that file really missing on the filesystem? Or it is there?

Comment: Yes this file is absent. In fact it is in /usr/lib64/python2.7/config/Makefile
The main question is: why it is run from CL and is not run from python module.

Comment: No idea on why it does that. It looks as an installation problem to me, maybe you could try asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)...

Comment: Try adding the option `shell=True`.

Comment: Just as a side question, why are you running test.py through a subprocess and not importing it as a module into your project?

Comment: I'm developing auto tests for some project. And now I want to run tests in parallel. So I'm going to create python script collecting and running test modules. In fact it would be like:
subprocess.call(["python","test1.py"])
...
subprocess.call(["python","testN.py"])

Comment: but subprocess won't return before the called process is done

Comment: have you tried calling python with a full path? also, at least RHEL doesn't like when you replace its original python 2.4, or so I heard, which made me install python27 with altinstall (into /usr/local/...). don't know if same is true for Fedora, but might be worth a try, maybe there's some sort of hickup there

Comment: My mistake. It will be "popen". But it doesn't cancel the question. With popen I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately full path didn't help.

Comment: I guess the only difference between you calling python from the shell and python calling itself via popen or whatever is in the environment variables. could check if there's something important in the environment, and if it's carried over when you run popen, not sure myself actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using something like pydev for development.

If you have a look at the "Interpreter" tab in the "Run Configurations", you should see the python path (with the "See resulting command-line...") and the binary used for the command. Pydev alters the PYTHONPATH (it's not the same as you have in the command line).

I'd suggest you should try having a look inside (or even try to run the command line with the same PYTHONPATH as in pydev and see if you get the same errors.

HTH

Comment: PS: This should not have any bearing on the linux release or the 32/64 bit IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've cleaned up PYTHONPATH in Eclipse and now it works.